# nginx adds extra line breaks on long oauth access token

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0

when I tried the [OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection with NGINX and njs](https://github.com/nginxinc/NGINX-Demos/tree/master/oauth2-token-introspection-oss)
 it seems that nginx adds extra line breaks on the incoming, long access token. therefore although the newly generated oauth2 access token is still fresh and valid, the *proxy_pass* for *_oauth2_send_introspection_request* always returns

```
{ active: false }
```

However, when the same access token is being used with PostMan to directly communicate with the samen introspect endpoint http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect, it has successfully retrieved info on the concerned subject.

In order to further confirm this issue, I've explicitly added a new location on the same virtual host (127.0.0.1:**9590**) in nginx, which will proxy to the same endpoint for introspect, http://localhost:**8080**/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect

```
location /auth/ {
   proxy_set_header Host 127.0.0.1:8080;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

When I tried to post the same access token with PostMan to http://localhost:**9590**/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect, the same issue is reproduced.

In order to investigate this issue, I've enabled *io.undertow.server.handlers.RequestDumpingHandler* with keycloak and found that nginx actually split the long access token into multiple lines (with extra line breaks), which has resulted in the active: false response from keycloak when introspect is being proxied to keycloak via nginx

The following examples show how the post data respectively look like with POST proxied by nginx and the POST directly communicated with introspect with PostMan

> token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJUUUNjeXdscHlHdmhCWl9wSXFQN21mckVaaXl0VFl3NmFDUkY5V3h2V29rIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJhNmFmNGE1MS1mMDZkLTRhMjctODZiZS1mMDAxZWI4NGJmYmUiLCJleHAiOjE1NzgwNDMzMjUsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTc4MDQzMDI1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvZGV2IiwiYXVkIjoiYWNjb3VudCIsInN1YiI6ImJiYWZiNDlkLWMxYzUtNDQwYS04OTEyLTNiNj
>   g4ZWQzOGEwNiIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImVtcGxveWVlLXNlcnZpY2UiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjAsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiI3ZjdjNDMwNy00OTI4LTRjMmMtYTFlOC05Y2FlMDYwMjhmY2UiLCJhY3IiOiIxIiwicmVhbG1fYWNjZXNzIjp7InJvbGVzIjpbIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIiwidW1hX2F1dGhvcml6YXRpb24iXX0sInJlc291cmNlX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJhY2NvdW50Ijp7InJvbGVzIjpbIm1hbmFnZS1hY2NvdW50IiwibWFuYWdlLWFjY291bnQtbGlua3MiLC
>   J2aWV3LXByb2ZpbGUiXX0sImVtcGxveWVlLXNlcnZpY2UiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsidW1hX3Byb3RlY3Rpb24iXX19LCJzY29wZSI6ImVtYWlsIHByb2ZpbGUiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsImNsaWVudElkIjoiZW1wbG95ZWUtc2VydmljZSIsImNsaWVudEhvc3QiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJzZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnQtZW1wbG95ZWUtc2VydmljZSIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6InNlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC1lbXBsb3llZS1zZXJ2aWNlIiwiY2
>   xpZW50QWRkcmVzcyI6IjEyNy4wLjAuMSIsImVtYWlsIjoic2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50LWVtcGxveWVlLXNlcnZpY2VAcGxhY2Vob2xkZXIub3JnIn0.PGI4TVlPWtQx1bhK7LPsS24TcHLAlRG1kRawaRpcO1AbDHenwa41Mg0HtriZdA_jSxhGTeYKLq-ygAppvnl7b7jKza_pWXdDVbRt7Ko88UPetmQuXIPA7C7yHkL_gQrL1XsYIyvvkxAnL_6w2odVA-OPb3zeC-ZVLcPQz6kcoyoE7BXi5GupBBsC1fwDXmwI8jk8DzbzRS8lsidnZJVS73ngJoD4x29u6LBXj2ZnmK7ZqMQyOQWBy9jAGy
>   CMNPwuF-wOFVG9vODfnZdgUDrJSZmsuA173AVqcdJl52l_42COYgoQxhCGFKnb22comRVeWlAj_bMBAsUH04HRLTJfyQ

token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJUUUNjeXdscHlHdmhCWl9wSXFQN21mckVaaXl0VFl3NmFDUkY5V3h2V29rIn0.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.PGI4TVlPWtQx1bhK7LPsS24TcHLAlRG1kRawaRpcO1AbDHenwa41Mg0HtriZdA_jSxhGTeYKLq-ygAppvnl7b7jKza_pWXdDVbRt7Ko88UPetmQuXIPA7C7yHkL_gQrL1XsYIyvvkxAnL_6w2odVA-OPb3zeC-ZVLcPQz6kcoyoE7BXi5GupBBsC1fwDXmwI8jk8DzbzRS8lsidnZJVS73ngJoD4x29u6LBXj2ZnmK7ZqMQyOQWBy9jAGyCMNPwuF-wOFVG9vODfnZdgUDrJSZmsuA173AVqcdJl52l_42COYgoQxhCGFKnb22comRVeWlAj_bMBAsUH04HRLTJfyQ

Answer (score 0):

I've found one simple solution

```
proxy_request_buffering on;
```